# Path matches Route but the component for that route is not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

my component for the Route is this:

```
const Workout = props => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Workout;
```

then I import this component to my **index.js**

```
import Workout from "./views/Workout";
```

then I define my **Route**:

```
<Route exact path="/:weekId/:dayId:/work" component={Workout} />
```

I hit the route in the browser:

```
codesandbox.io/week-1/day-1/work
```

but nothing is rendered, no error and no console.log :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path variable should be `:dayId`, not `:dayId:`.

**Example**

```
const Workout = props => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/:weekId/:dayId/work" component={Workout} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```